# Регулярное выражение только латинские буквы?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Помогите задать регулярное вырожение для только латинских букв.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` - правда, тут лишние буквы учитываются

Comment: @mymedia, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще говоря, пока мой комментарий сложно назвать полноценным ответом.

Comment: @mymedia Этот вопрос тоже трудно назвать полноценным...

Comment: @Harry а что не так с вопросом? Слишком простой на ваш взгляд?

Comment: @NickVolynkin На мой взгляд - да. Это азы, простейшее. Т.е. я понимаю вопрос хотя бы как регулярку для, скажем, e-mail'ов сделать - но просто для букв?

Comment: @Harry вроде же неважно простой вопрос или нет, важно атомарный ли он и может ли быть полезным будущим читателям

Comment: @diraria Ну не верю я что-то в то, что кто-то зайдет сюда в поисках, чему равно 2*2 (утрирую, конечно, но...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если верить Википедии, то в [классическом латинском](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82) алфавите ровно 23
буквы: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `K`, `L`, `M`, `N`, `O`,
`P`, `Q`, `R`, `S`, `T`, `V`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`.

К счастью, их не придётся перечислять все в нашем регулярном выражении - можно
схитрить и положиться на порядок символов в [таблице ASCII](https://ostermiller.org/calc/ascii.html). Тогда получится
нечто такое:

```
[a-ik-tvxyz]
```

Использовать для регистранезависимого поиска можно примерно так:

```
std::regex r("[a-ik-tvxyz]+", std::regex::icase);
...
```

Comment: Откуда инфа, что ТС нужен именно "классический" вариант алфавита?

Comment: ну написано же: "для латинских букв"; да и в конце концов, какая разница, что там нужно автору вопроса :)